# Internationalization in PHP

Tags: php, internationalization

I am currently researching the best methods to integrate `i18n` into projects.

There's several methods I have thought of doing this, first being a database scheme to store the strings and relevant locale, but the problem with this is that it would not be that easy to select the strings, because i would not like to perform quesries like so:

```
SELECT text FROM locales WHERE locale = 'en_GB' AND text_id = 245543
```

Or

```
SELECT text FROM locales WHERE locale = 'en_GB' AND text_primary = 'hello'
```

The next method would be to store them within files such as `locales/en_gb/login/strings.php` and then try and access them via an class specifically developed like so:

```
$Language = Registry::Construct('Language',array('en_GB'));
echo $Language->login->strings->hello;
```

The issue with this is I would have to build a system that would update these files via an administration panel witch is very time consuming, not just building the system to manage the strings but actually managing the strings as the site grows

- What other methods are there that will be beneficial for a large system
- Is there any automated way to do 'Translation' as such
- Should I stick with a database method and build a system for users to translate strings with rating / suggest better version ?
- What systems have you tried in the past and should I look into them or totally avoid them.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to `gettext` already mentioned, [PHP 5.3 has native Internationalization support](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

If that's not an option, consider using Zend Framework's [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html), [`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html) and related components for that. `Zend_Translate` supports a number of adapters, including but not limited to simple arrays, gettext, XmlTm and others.

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented a XML translation utility as part of a bigger project. You can find it [here](http://github.com/halfdan/mongoui/blob/master/core/Translate.php), and a sample translation file is [here](http://github.com/halfdan/mongoui/blob/master/lang/en_US.xml) (en_US).

Comment: They're not comitted yet. This project is relatively new, so I'm in the process of building up the framework. UnitTests are coming in the next few days.

Comment: Great, i love the XML Formation rather then using things such as Arrays / objects, makes depth more simpler :) +1

Comment: It should be pretty easy to write a GUI tool for translators too. Haven't had the time to write one though :)

Comment: Amazing LIBRARY!!! I loved it, seriously. I'll check the rest of your libs, it looks very interesting your project (I guess is everything yours). 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The most impressive method to study is Drupal's implementation. Second best, would be Wordpress. Both use gettext and .pot/.po/.mo for localization. And, the good thing is that there is a beautiful Open Source .po editor called Poedit. It's available for Windows System users, which gives a wider appeal. It's also available for Mac and Linux. Check it out here: http://www.poedit.net/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Gettext (http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) library.

Don't put your text into a database. That'll just make life hard on the translation team.