# PHP multi-language

Tags: php, html, internationalization, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internationalization in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760499/internationalization-in-php)

I'm looking for a simple and performant way of adding multi-language to a PHP site. I'm not trying to be lazy, I'm simply looking for the best approach since there are so many different approaches out there. I've already searched alot on the internet but I'm still looking for the best solution to date.

You can either store your translations in your database or in a php file. I prefer the last in order to reduce the amount of calls to the db. 
What do you guys think/prefer?

Any good tutorials about this are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Which approaches have you ruled-out so far in your research - and for what reason(s)? What are your specific criteria(s)? I'm asking because in it's current form your question is too broad and it's subjective and that's the kind of questions we don't like to see here, see the FAQ.

Comment: The storing in DB i've ruled out so far. But i'm still doubting how i would approach this with php files (html variables or with an array)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an include file for each language which stores constants. The constants have the same name for every language, and depending on the user selection, you include the right language file.

But I'd recommend this only for simple things like Login text, not for the content itself.

Overall it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: This sound like a perfect comment, especially the last sentence.

Comment: It's for a website with approx 10-15 pages