# Multiple language implemention in php using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-translate

I am new to php. On my website I have created a list box of all the languages, but I don't know how to translate my English content to Chinese or to Spanish basically I need a translation code of a particular language.

I have made a langauge table with is attributes as `Lang_id`, `Lang_name`.

Comment: Would using [Google Translate's API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) suffice?

Comment: Do you want to actually translate content automatically? or just swap out bits of text for already translated pieces?

the former is extremely complex and would be better served by using a translation API. take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: [Internationalization in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760499/internationalization-in-php). PHP 5.3 supports native internationalization (http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)

Comment: yes i want to translate content automatically and I have made a langauge table with is attributes as language(Lang_id, Lang_name).
and i have put languages like English,chinese,spanish,french. I just need to know how I would translate the whole content. basically i need a translation code

Comment: Ok, then you have to use a translation api like https://developers.google.com/translate/ (EM-Creations already mentioned it). Here is an example: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/translate/simple.php

Answer (score 0):

Make dedicated page like : "lang.php" having codes like

```
0 = for English
1 = Italian
2 = French

$me_user_name = array('Username','nome utente','','','Nom d\'utilisateur')
```

use this array on your site.

for ex.:

```
echo $me_user_name[0] // to print in english
```

Comment: I just want to know how i translate the english content to hindi or chinese content..
 I have made a langauge table with is attributes as language(Lang_id, Lang_name). and i have put languages like English,chinese,spanish,french.